# Control Managed Resources created when deploying Azure Purview with ARM

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-purview

Can I control in the ARM Template the **managed resources** storage account, eventhub created when deploying Azure Purview with an ARM Template.
For example not deploying an Eventhub and configuring the network connection for the storage account public vs private instead of needing to make the change after the deployment?
It seems like in the ARM Template I can only control the name of the managed resource
Using the Starter Template Provided on Github
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.azurepurview/azure-purview-deployment/azuredeploy.json

I have the following and I would like to be able to configure the managed resource group in more detail

```
"properties": {
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
        "managedResourceGroupName": "[format('managed-rg-{0}', parameters('purviewName'))]"
      }
enter code here
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any approach? If so share the code and error details.

Comment: Hi, I added some details in the question basically starting from the Github ARM Template and trying to configure the managed resource group storage etc...  Not sure how.